# Next.js use of _app.js and _document.js

Tags: next.js

I currently use `_document.js` to inject css into my Next.js app and I would like to start using `_app.js` to help inject data into pages.

Was wondering if it possible to use _document and _app in tandem or should we only use one or the other?

Comment: Here is a comparsion betwen _app.js and _document.js https://zeit.co/blog/next6#app-component
In short you can use both.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, You can use both. They serve different purpose and can be used in the same application.

According to [NextJS docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app):

> Next.js uses the App component to initialize pages.
>
> To override, create the `./pages/_app.js` file and override the App class

and

> Pages in Next.js skip the definition of the surrounding document's markup. For example, you never include `<html>`, `<body>`, etc. To override that default behavior, you must create a file at `./pages/_document.js`, where you can extend the Document class.

**Note**: `_document.js` is only rendered on the server side and not on the client side. so event handlers like `onClick` is not going to work.

Comment: So _app is only rendered on client side and _document on server side? Does on wraps the other -_document wrapping _app or reverse? thanks for any hint

Comment: @Webwoman `_app.js` is rendered on both server-side and client-side (on the server during the initial SSR, on the client-side after hydration and then on every page/route navigation). `_document.js` "wraps" `_app.js`.

Comment: Where's the documentation for _app?

Comment: It would appear `_app.js` is only mentioned in the 'Learn' section here: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/global-styles

Note: you will need to restart your server after adding it.

Comment: hello there is it SAFE to inject env variables into the _document.js html head tag ? thanks

Comment: @mangrove108 it will work, I don't know what you mean by "safe". I wouldn't advise you to inject confidential information there since it will be visible to the client, but why would you want to access `process.env` from `_document.js`?

Comment: i am still a bit confused about ssr and env in nextjs. Guess i need to study more

Comment: There are valid use cases for exposing env vars, but it's recommended to only use those with the explicit `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix, which are meant to be public.  Currently using this to output build info for debugging purposes (e.g. build time, git commit hash)

Comment: documentation for _app can be found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app